# Обьясните данную кострукцию arr.push

Tags: javascript

Я читал про метод массива `arr.push` добавляет в конец массива елемент.Но тут у меня проблема.Проблема заключается в том что я на данный момент читаю код другого программиста а там такая функция

```
function generate_array_multi( arr, min_val_2, max_val_2 )
{
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = min_val_2; j <= max_val_2; j++ ) {
            arr.push( {"a1" : i, "a2" : j} );
            arr.push( {"a1" : j, "a2" : i} );
        }
    }
}
```

Вот та часть которая мне непонятно.

```
arr.push( {"a1" : j, "a2" : i} );
```

Не где не смог найти похожую конструкцию.

> **Вопрос:что добавляется в конец массива** ?

И если это обьект то в следующем примере присутствует выражения внутри метода `push` это законно вообще ?

```
function generate_array_diviz( arr, min_val_2, max_val_2 )
{
    for ( var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ ) {
        for ( var j = min_val_2; j <= max_val_2; j++ ) {
            arr.push( {"a1" : i*j, "a2" : j} );//i*j
            arr.push( {"a1" : j*i, "a2" : i} );//i*j обясните это подробнее пожалуйста
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: просто обьект значения свойств которого вычисляються перед добавлением

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych ну если это обьект где его имя откуда он берётся ?

Comment: `{"a1" : j*i, "a2" : i}` - вот отсюда и береться (он тут создается), а имя то ему зачем ? ему и без имени норм :)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych спасибо большое все ясно.Если хотите напишите ответ я приму его :)

Comment: Объекты не имеют имени, имена есть только у переменных, которые ссылаются на эти объекты (arr, i и т.д.), и у полей объектов (a1, a2 и т.д.), ну и иногда у функций

Comment: @andreymal Ого про это я  тоже незнал спасибо и вам